# Ordenar diccionario a partir de llaves usando un texto en especifico de la llave en Python

Tags: python, lista, estructuras-de-datos, diccionarios, ordenamiento

Estoy tratando de ordenar un objeto en Python a partir de las llaves, pero teniendo en cuenta que las llaves internamente tienen en la cadena de texto mi identificador (este identificador si o si tiene que estar dentro, por otro tipo de especificaciones)
Mi código es algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
aminoacidos = {'DAB3:Hidrogeno 4': {'HB': 9, 'HI': 11},
                'DAB1:Nitrogeno 5': {'HB': 3, 'HI': 1},
                'THR2:Oxigeno 7': {'HB': 4, 'HI': 6},
                'LEU4:Carbonp 3': {'HB': 2, 'HI': 7}}

nuevoOrden = sorted(aminoacidos, key=lambda aminoacid: aminoacid[3:])
```

Aquí deseo organizarlo de acuerdo al numero en la posición 3 de la llave, que vendría siendo un numero (mi identificador).
Quisiera obtener un resultado como el siguiente:

```
nuevoOrden =  {'DAB1:Nitrogeno 5': {'HB': 3, 'HI': 1},
                'THR2:Oxigeno 7': {'HB': 4, 'HI': 6},
                'DAB3:Hidrogeno 4': {'HB': 9, 'HI': 11},
                'LEU4:Carbonp 3': {'HB': 2, 'HI': 7}}
```

He estado buscando la manera de ordenarlo de esa manera pero no he podido. Cuando ejecuto ese código, me sigue apareciendo la misma lista sin ordenar
Alguien me puede iluminar?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Cual seria el resultado que esperas?

Comment: Y por favor agrega el código que has intentado, es importante que muestres un esfuerzo por resolver tu problema

Comment: Con la edición lo que entiendo es que ¿Deseas ordenar de acuerdo al cuarto caracter de tu llave? ¿Ese identificador siempre va a estar en esa posición?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato si exacto, ese identificado siempre estará en esa posición

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar el método [`sorted()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) con el argumento `key`, que recibe una función sobre la cuál poder ordenar.

En tu caso, el número identificador siempre viene en el índice 3 de las llaves de tu diccionario así que bastaría con obtener ese valor de cada llave

Definimos una función que lo obtenga:

```
def get_id_index(k):
    return k[3]
```

Luego utilizamos esa función en `sorted()` y va a ordenar las llaves de acuerdo a el tercer caracter en tu `string` de las llaves

Ejemplo completo:

```
aminoacidos = {'DAB3:Hidrogeno 4': {'HB': 9, 'HI': 11},
                'DAB1:Nitrogeno 5': {'HB': 3, 'HI': 1},
                'THR2:Oxigeno 7': {'HB': 4, 'HI': 6},
                'LEU4:Carbonp 3': {'HB': 2, 'HI': 7}}

def get_id_index(k):
    return k[3]

sorted(aminoacidos.keys(), key=get_id_index)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['DAB1:Nitrogeno 5', 'THR2:Oxigeno 7', 'DAB3:Hidrogeno 4', 'LEU4:Carbonp 3']
```

**Nota:** Este código únicamente va a obtener un caracter, el que esté en el índice 3 de tu llave. Si en algún momento tu número identificador fuera de 2 o más dígitos entonces podrías utilizar un `regex` para obtener el número completo (Eso te quedaría de tarea)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió bastante y además tu sintaxis me sirvio para otro inconveniente en otro código que tenia.